# How to use third party libraries with identical class name or function name

Tags: c++

If we used a library which has `class classA` and the other library which has `class classB` or the same situation on functions name and we want to compile these libraries in our program, how can we do it? (for example in QT)

Comment: Don't these libraries use namespaces to avoid such name collisions?

Comment: Qt can be configured to use its own namespace, but it has to be recompiled for this purpose, so you can't use provided ready-made packages.

Comment: @vahancho I use `sanp stanford` and `caffe` in my program and none of them have namespace.

Comment: @Murphy this collision is not in qt classes or functions name, just is between `sanp stanford` and `caffe`

Comment: Then why did you mention Qt at all, added the tag and didn't provide information about the actual collisions instead?

Comment: @Murphy I eliminated QT in question header. This question is general and I think there is no need to specify exact libraries. (Why did you change your plus to mines immediately?!)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options:

### Wrapper

Make another library that wraps one of third party libraries by linking it statically and by not exporting any symbols from it.

Use that wrapper library in your program.

### Dynamic load

Load both third party libraries dynamically with something like `dlopen()` in your program and get addresses of each of their symbols with `dlsym()`.

Comment: Thanks, in my program, I have `snap stanford` library which I compile it and it has name collision with `caffe` library. So I should change the accessibility to `snap stanford`. so which one is better solution?

Comment: The developers of these libraries are using namespaces, there shouldn't be a collision. What is the collision?

Comment: When I use `snap` and add header and source files of that to my project  and after that I use `caffe` so in compiling, the error like this appears: `error: ‘ExeStop’ declared as function returning a function` and also `error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘__null’ in ‘ExeStop’`.

Comment: The `ExeStop` is in `bd.h` and `bd.cpp` in `snap` folder, and non of these files use namespace.